# Adding custom ivars to iOS tweak

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, tweak, theos

How should I define my own instance variables in something like the following code in a tweak? Here `myBool` is new. I'm using Theos/Logos with iOS 7.0.4. Is this possible? Can't find anything about it anywhere. I know about MSHookIvar but that only works with existing variables.

```
@interface SBApplication {
    BOOL myBool;
}

- (void)setBadge:(id)arg1;

@end

%hook SBApplication

- (void)setBadge:(id)arg1 {
    %orig;

    if(myBool == NO){
        NSLog(@"myBool is NO");
    }
}

%end
```

Comment: Associated objects are as close as you can get easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think you can add ivar to en existing class. There is `class_addIvar` function but it doesn't work with existing classes. In your case, `SBApplication` already defined so you can't add an ivar into it.

I can suggest very simple solution - static/global (or both) variables. It can be, for example, `BOOL` variable if you need just one variable. Or it could be an array of object-variable pairs if you want variable for every class instance. The latter will work just like a class ivar.

Comment: I went with the latter, indeed. I made a global `NSMutableDictionary` and used it with the app bundle identifiers as keys. Works great.